# Forest Inventory Plots in QGIS 3.2

Tags: qgis

I have created inventory points within each polygon and will be navigating to each point via GPS. Upon completion of each plot, I would like to change the symbology (color)of the point in order to better keep up with the completed and not completed plots. What would be the best way to do this in the field, most likely using QField?

Comment: Yes, however does not have to be automatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Rule based layer styling. For example I have a point layer with two fields: "height" and "acceptable". If both have values the symbol is green, else red:

```
"height" is not null and  "acceptable" is not null
```

[image]

[image]

Another option is to create a lable. The same logic can be used.